# Is this phrase ok?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I started reading an other book where I read, in its *Introduction*, the  phrase  written in bold below (I am quoting the full paragraph in which it is mentioned) which I do not understand because it seems to me the meaning is *cut* somehow. Or maybe I am missing something. Note that when the bold phrase below ends, a totally new paragraph begins:

> I have discovered that as we learn to accept change as a fact of life,
>   and accept grief and growth cycles as a definition of the process that  makes us "change resilient", creativity increases. Every time we manifest 
>    our personality -some aspect of how we think, what we think, who we like, what we do, how we see and solve a problem, how we express our feelings- every single way we, "Insist on ourselves!" as Emerson would say, we paint a picture of the world to see.
>   **The stronger and bolder these pictures become mirror our courage to
>   face crisis and overcome them, using life energy in the service of
>   growth.**

For me, the phrase would make sense only if we put a comma between *become* and *mirror*, where *mirror* is a verb not a noun. Otherwise, I am not able to understand this. Please clarify me if you know.

P.S. The paragraph I quoted exists in a book called: [*Taking Advantage of Adversity: How to Move from Crisis to Creativity*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0751532851)

Comment: It might help if you would identify the book and/or provide more of the paragraph that contains this sentence.

Comment: It would make more sense if the previous sentence ended '...a picture _for_ the world to see'. I'm sure 'mirror' is meant to be a verb. If we present a strong image of ourselves, it shows that we have courage to face crisis (crises?).

Comment: I agree with your notion that a comma is warranted here. In Dutch, it is **required** to put a comma between two verbs (that are not part of the same subclause). Although English tends to often place commas there too, I am not sure if it is an actual **requirement** (hence why this is a comment, not an answer).

Comment: If you mean cut as in skipped or condensed, yes, you could look at it that way. Let's grant that standards for pop books don't need to match the classics. I'd process it easier if it said "The stronger and bolder these pictures become, *the more they* mirror our courage" or "Stronger and bolder pictures mirror our courage." In the second version, the words the/these/become dropped out.

Comment: I agree that the sentence as written is awkwardly worded if not outright ungrammatical. I don't think that a comma would fix it, though: @YosefBaskin's suggestion is on point.

Comment: *awkwardly worded if not outright ungrammatical.* Interesting to hear. Hope someone can develop that. @MarkBeadles

Comment: This seems like one of those sentences that started off in one direction and then went in another.  The editor gets an F.

Comment: Could you please come up with a more descriptive title, as it reads now it is fairly meaningless. I guarantee a good title will encourage more visits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The presenting sentence:

- *??The stronger and bolder these pictures become mirror our courage to

      face crises and overcome them, using life energy in the service of growth.*

is crammed with distractions that have nothing to do with the verb *mirror*,
which is at issue. But if we chop down the sentence to the basics it becomes
incomprehensible, i.e. ungrammatical:

- **The stronger and bolder these pictures become mirror our courage.*

This is almost certainly a mistake for a sentence with the construction normally called
***the `X`-er, the `Y`-er***, where the `Y` component has been left out inadvertently:

- *The stronger and bolder these pictures become, **the more they** mirror our courage.*

So the answer to the question is that a missing pronoun (*they*), coreferential with *pictures*,
is the subject of *mirror*. But it's put together ungrammatically in the original.

Comment: I decide to reward the bounty for you because, as I am a self-taught in this language, I needed someone to answer me in a confident way as you did. There is a user here who did not answer to my comment (now deleted) while I was seeking for a confident answerer who is not scared to say the author is wrong and, more importantly, be clear with me.

Answer (score 9):

I had noted in a comment that the bolded sentence in the original was "awkwardly worded, if not outright ungrammatical". Here's why:

> The stronger and bolder these pictures become mirror our courage to face crisis and overcome them, using life energy in the service of growth.

To wit: **what is the subject of the verb 'mirror'?**

- '*These pictures*'? No, that noun phrase seems to be the subject of 'become'.
- '*The stronger and bolder*'? That doesn't seem to be a noun phrase, and even if it is, it's the complement to 'become' and can't stand as a subject of "mirror".

In the comment from @Yosef Baskin above, he makes the admirable suggestion that the sentence would be more clear as follows:

> The stronger and bolder these pictures become, ***the more they*** mirror our courage to face crisis and overcome them, using life energy in the service of growth.

Which would make 'they' (referring to 'these pictures') the subject of mirror, leaving the sense intact while avoiding the awkward phrasing. One could also write:

> ***As these pictures become*** stronger and bolder, they mirror our courage to face crisis and overcome them, using life energy in the service of growth.

It seems that somewhere in the writing or editing process, the sentence got a bit too complex and stumbled over itself.

Comment: As has been remarked, it's an awkward construction but not indecipherable and perhaps not even ungrammatical. The entire phrase "The stronger and bolder these pictures become" seems to me the subject of mirror, but as a concept, so as jlovegren notes below, mirror should be mirrors to agree with a singular subject.

Answer (score 3):

The author is confusing English idiomatic expressions and mistaking number agreement. He probably wants to say:

> The strength and courage depicted in these pictures mirrors our courage to face crises and overcome them [in real life], using life energy in the service of growth.

The author is saying, to use an American expression, "fake it 'till you make it." Act like you are strong and courageous, then in real life you'll find yourself actually becoming more strong and courageous.

Comment: strength and courage = plural. therefore: mirror

Comment: @Vekzhivi no, they are mass nouns. even if they were singular, they are coordinated to make a plural noun phrase.

Comment: @jlovegren Except for the first word "no" in your comment, you seem to be agreeing with Vekzhivi: The subject, "strength and courage", is plural and therefore needs a plural verb "mirror".

Comment: @AndreasBlass that's funny. Yes, I am agreeing with Vekzhivi in the abstract. But it still needs to be *mirrors*.

Answer (score -1):

The answers and the edited versions of the disputed line are really unique, and some renditions are even improvement over the original itself. But, to my mind, at the time of texting, proof reading or printing an unassuming preposition, "OF" slipped off unobtrusively, and caused all this trouble. The fuss is all about this missing preposition of "OF".

- The stronger and bolder these pictures become mirror -/
  OF/  - our courage...

OF. Used to introduce subjunctive genitive; following a noun to form the head of a post modifying noun phrase. A Wiktionary example:

- Valentino repeatedly solicits the attention (of ) women who have turned away from him.

OF  dethroned is now reinstated, and the meaning is discernable.

Comment: That should be *become **a** mirror of our courage*.

Comment: Read 'mirror' as replica in abstract sense as of Spencer's, " O goddess heavenly bright, / Mirror of grace and majesty divine ". What matters, if it be 'a'! Aren't we all  in that  nasty game of correcting?